# After Match Group block, in ForceCommand can I somehow refer to the username (etc.) in a generic fashion?

Tags: openssh, sshd

Suppose I am using [`Match Group`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#Match) and inside of that block I am using [`ForceCommand`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ForceCommand) is there a way to refer to the name of the connecting user or the user's home folder in a similar fashion [`AuthorizedKeysFile`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#AuthorizedKeysFile) can use the [tokens](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#TOKENS) `%h`, `%U`, and `%u`?

Alternatively does `ForceCommand` get the contents of these tokens in some other form? That is, if I use `/etc/ssh/sshrc` to output environment variables I get to see `$USER`, `$HOME` et cetera; is it appropriate/allowed to use those inside `ForceCommand`?

In case it matters: I am using version 8.2p1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is run as the use you are connecting to. Thus, you have `$USER`, `$LOGNAME`, `$HOME`, etc. set to that same user. There's no problem in using them.

The command itself is run with the user shell (usually bash, so `/bin/bash -c 'your_forcecommand'`), so you can include such variables in the ForceCommand and they will be expanded by the shell.

[`sshd_config` states](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ForceCommand):

> The command is invoked by using the user's login shell with the -c option.

You can [find in OpenSSH code](https://anongit.mindrot.org/openssh.git/tree/auth.c?h=V_8_4#n913) that it sets `PATH`, `USER`, `LOGNAME` and `HOME`.

Comment: Could you please provide an authoritative reference?! After all what you wrote is something I have pointed out in my question. Now the part that I am _really_ interested in is if this can break. For example there are certain preconditions to `/etc/ssh/sshrc` being used and the part I want to know is whether I can _rely_ on those environment variables. Thanks.

Comment: @0xC0000022L sshd_config states "The command is invoked by using the user's login shell with the -c option." You can [find in openssh code](https://anongit.mindrot.org/openssh.git/tree/auth.c?h=V_8_4#n913) that it sets `PATH`, `USER`, `LOGNAME` and `HOME`. I'm not sure how to provide you a more authoritative reference...

Comment: that's perfectly fine. Thanks. Added the references to your answer.